# Css selector conflicts

Tags: css

I'm adding a gallery feature to my blog and the gallery looks like this.

```
<ul id="pikeme" class="pika-thumbs">
 <li>image</li>
 <li>image</li>
</ul>
```

The gallery plugin gets is styling from `.pika-thumbs li` - however there is also the default blog styling `.text ul li` that is also applying its effects on the gallery - which I don't want. Is there a way to exclude `.text ul li` styling from the gallery?

Thanks!

Comment: The not so nice `!important` would fit here, assuming you can't change the gallery stylesheet.

Comment: However, if you can change the gallery stylesheet, check @SW4 answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:not`, e.g:

Change

`.text ul li`

To
`.text ul:not(#pikeme) li`

Or

`.text ul:not(.pika-thumbs) li`

**[More on `:not` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)**

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Lq41yvo7/)**

use the ID selector `#pikeme li` to override the `.text ul li`

> As ID selector has greater priority than class selector.

css

```
#pikeme li { /* instead of .pika-thumbs li */
    color: red;
}
```